# Breeze when adding item many to many I need refresh page to add new item

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, breeze

**Please skip this and read edit :)**

I have entity which serves as many to many mapping for two other entities:

```
public class ExerciseAndCategory
    {

        #region Navigational properties

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual ExerciseCategory ExerciseCategory { get; set; }


        public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
```

Here is FluentApi for it:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseAndCategory>().HasKey(e => new {e.ExerciseId, e.CategoryId});


            modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseAndCategory>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Exercise)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ExerciseId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ExerciseAndCategory>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.ExerciseCategory)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.CategoryId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

And in database that looks like this:

[image: Database]

To get and save data I'm using BreezeApi Controller, and I'm adding data as it is showed in breeze samples:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }
```

And In service (using Breeze) I send data to api like this:

```
addExerciseAndCategories: function (data, initialValues) {

            var addedExercise = manager.createEntity("Exercise", initialValues);

            _.forEach(data, function (item) {
                var entity = manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory", { ExerciseId: addedExercise._backingStore.ExerciseId, CategoryId: item.CategoryId });
                items.push(entity);

            });
            saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

            function addFailed() {
                removeItem(items, item);
            }
        },
```

With this I can add item to database, but if I want to add another one without refreshing,

I get exception at this part of code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }
```

Saying

```
DBUpdateException was unhandeled by user code
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

And in Javascript console:

```
 "Error: Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ExerciseAndCategories_dbo.Exercises_ExerciseId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-Web.UserInterface.Web-20130806182934", table "dbo.Exercises", column 'ExerciseId'.
The statement has been terminated."
```

But if I refresh after adding, everything works fine. (i.e. I can add another item)

**EDIT**

I've found very bad workaround for a problem. And problem is that, ExerciseId is -1 before calling saveChanges(). I've decided to separate adding exercise and categories in two different functions. And my code looked like this:

```
addExercise: function (initialValues) {
            exerciseToAdd = manager.createEntity("Exercise", initialValues);
            saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

            function addFailed() {
                removeItem(items, item);
            }
        },
```

addExerciseAndCategories: function(data) {
            newItems = [];

```
        logger.log("id is", exerciseToAdd.ExerciseId);
        _.forEach(data, function(item) {
            var entity = manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory", { ExerciseId: exerciseToAdd.ExerciseId, CategoryId: item.CategoryId });
            items.push(entity);
            newItems.push(entity);

        });
        saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

        var itemsToAdd = addCategoriesToExercise(newItems);

        _.forEach(itemsToAdd, function(item) {
            exerciseAndCategories.push(item);
        });
    }
```

And this didn't work, same error. So in console I've noticed that ExerciseId is still -1, and then I decided to use angular's $timeout and wait for a few seconds and then log ExerciseId, after that ExerciseId was int greater than -1, i.e. it worked fine, so I've changed code to this (and everything works as it should):

```
addExerciseAndCategories: function(data) {
            newItems = [];

            $timeout(function() {
                logger.log("id je", exerciseToAdd.ExerciseId);
                _.forEach(data, function (item) {
                    var entity = manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory", { ExerciseId: exerciseToAdd.ExerciseId, CategoryId: item.CategoryId });
                    items.push(entity);
                    newItems.push(entity);

                });
                saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

                var itemsToAdd = addCategoriesToExercise(newItems);

            _.forEach(itemsToAdd, function(item) {
                exerciseAndCategories.push(item);
            });
            },5000); 


            function addFailed() {
                removeItem(items, item);
            }
        },
```

Finally, as I know this is very bad solution, my question is, how can I get around this ? Is there any way for me to know that Exercise was inserted into database and that ExerciseId isn't -1 anymore ? Or can I generate ExerciseId (which is int) on client-side ?

Answer (score 0):

Breeze does not yet support many to many relationship for Entity Framework, although it is on our roadmap. Please vote for it on the Breeze User Voice [here](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3317477-many-many-relationship-for-ef).  As a workaround you can use two one-many relations with your mapping table exposed as an entity in the middle.

For example: if you have a conceptual many to many relationship like this:

```
Employee (m) <-->  (m) Territory 

Properties: Employee.Territories (m)
            Territory.Employees (m)
```

You can instead construct this by adding a new EntityType (EmpTerritory) in the middle:

```
Employee (1) <--> (m) EmpTerritory (m) <--> Territory (1)

Properties: Employee.EmployeeTerritories (m), 
            Territory.EmployeeTerritories (m),
            EmployeeTerritory.Employee (1), 
            EmployeeTerritory.Territory (1)
```

You can still navigate from an Employee to its Territories and vice versa, but you need to go thru the intermediate Entity first.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but isn't that what I'm doing ? I've exposed entity ExerciseAndCategory in the middle between Exercise and Category, or I'm doing it wrong ?

Comment: @JayTraband could you give us an example of how to use the work around?

Comment: More info added to the post above.